# Replace Matplotlib legend's labels with image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, legend

I would like to use image instead of labels in the legend.

For example, I draw 2 lines and show a legend :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2],label="first_image")
plt.plot([2,1],label="second_image")
plt.legend()
plot.show()
```

[image: What I have now]

But I would like to have something like this :

[image: The result I need]

Note that this is not a duplicate of [Insert image in matplotlib legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029592/insert-image-in-matplotlib-legend) ,
My issue is "change the label into an image", while the other is "change the legend's symbol into an image"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert image in matplotlib legend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029592/insert-image-in-matplotlib-legend)

Comment: Not directly related, but this example might lead you in the right direction: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The concept for creating an image in a legend is already presented in this question ([Insert image in matplotlib legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029592/insert-image-in-matplotlib-legend)) where an image is used as an artist for a legend entry.

In case you want a line handle and an image in the legend, the idea would be to create a handle that consists of both of them, positionned next to each other. 
The only problem is then to fine tune the parameters such that this looks appealing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox, TransformedBbox
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerBase
from matplotlib.image import BboxImage

class HandlerLineImage(HandlerBase):

    def __init__(self, path, space=15, offset = 10 ):
        self.space=space
        self.offset=offset
        self.image_data = plt.imread(path)        
        super(HandlerLineImage, self).__init__()

    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,
                       xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans):

        l = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([xdescent+self.offset,xdescent+(width-self.space)/3.+self.offset],
                                     [ydescent+height/2., ydescent+height/2.])
        l.update_from(orig_handle)
        l.set_clip_on(False)
        l.set_transform(trans)

        bb = Bbox.from_bounds(xdescent +(width+self.space)/3.+self.offset,
                              ydescent,
                              height*self.image_data.shape[1]/self.image_data.shape[0],
                              height)

        tbb = TransformedBbox(bb, trans)
        image = BboxImage(tbb)
        image.set_data(self.image_data)

        self.update_prop(image, orig_handle, legend)
        return [l,image]


plt.figure(figsize=(4.8,3.2))
line,  = plt.plot([1,2],[1.5,3], color="#1f66e0", lw=1.3)
line2,  = plt.plot([1,2],[1,2], color="#efe400", lw=1.3)
plt.ylabel("Flower power")

plt.legend([line, line2], ["", ""],
   handler_map={ line: HandlerLineImage("icon1.png"), line2: HandlerLineImage("icon2.png")}, 
   handlelength=2, labelspacing=0.0, fontsize=36, borderpad=0.15, loc=2, 
    handletextpad=0.2, borderaxespad=0.15)

plt.show()
```

[image]