# How can the position of a legend_handler in the legend box be adjusted in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a custom legend handler in matplotlib via looping over data. This handler includes a picture and a line, as kindly explained here (see: [Replace Matplotlib legend's labels with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155119/replace-matplotlib-legends-labels-with-image)). I understood that handler_map always updates the previous handler, therefore I generate it after plotting my lines. 
My problem is that the legend does not stay in the legend box but parts of it are outside the box. 
With the class described in the link above this piece of code reproduces the error:

```
class HandlerLineImage(HandlerBase):
 def __init__(self,path,space=15,offset=10):
  self.space=space
  self.offset=offset
  self.image_data = plt.imread(path)
  super(HandlerLineImage, self).__init__()

 def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle, xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans):
  l = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([xdescent+self.offset,xdescent+(width-self.space)/3.+self.offset],[ydescent+height/2., ydescent+height/2.])
  l.update_from(orig_handle)
  l.set_clip_on(False)
  l.set_transform(trans)
  bb = Bbox.from_bounds(xdescent +(width+self.space)/3.+self.offset,ydescent,height*self.image_data.shape[1]/self.image_data.shape[0],height)
  tbb = TransformedBbox(bb, trans)
  image = BboxImage(tbb)
  image.set_data(self.image_data)
  self.update_prop(image, orig_handle, legend)
  return [l,image]

def plotting(x_axis, y_axis, fig, color, lineliste, handler_map, legendliste):
 picturepath = path
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
 line, =  plt.plot(x_axis,y_axis, c=color)
 lineliste.append(line)
 handler_map[line] = HandlerLineImage(picturepath)
 legendliste.append('')
 return fig, lineliste, handler_map, legendliste


def main():
 fig = plt.figure()
 list_plotting=[[0,1,3,5], [0,0.1,0.2,0.3], [1,5,9,12], [0,1,1,3], [5,5,4,3], [8,7,6,5,]]
 lineliste = []
 legendliste = []
 handler_map = dict()
 plt.xlabel('values')
 colors = iter(cm.nipy_spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, len(list_plotting))))
 cnt_style = 0
 cnt_element = 0
 for element in list_plotting:
  x_values=range(len(element))
  y_values=element
  fig, lineliste, handler_map, legendliste = plotting(x_values, y_values, fig, next(colors), lineliste, handler_map, legendliste)
 plt.legend(handles = lineliste, labels = legendliste, handler_map = handler_map, handlelength=4, labelspacing=0.0, fontsize=36, borderpad=0.1, handletextpad=0.2, borderaxespad=0.1, handleheight=2, loc='upper center', frameon = True, bbox_to_anchor=(1.35,1.1))
 fig.savefig("output.pdf", format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
 plt.close(fig)

if __name__=='__main__':
 main()
```

I had the idea that anchored_bbox could lead into the right direction, but I was unable to figure it out. Same with AnnotationBbox or the idea that I somehow have to define a BBoxBase, which I also could not figure out. As I am rather new to python/matplotlib and this seems like an unusual/complicated error, I would be really glad if anyone could help!

Comment: The code isn't runnable. But I suspect you need to leave out `handleheight=2`.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot the call for main. I also added the class for convenience, but now it should work once you change path for your own picture. Leaving out handleheight only reduces the size of the picture, but the problem remains. Thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: Omg. your code just overwrote my image. I defused your code.

Comment: When I leave out `handleheight=2`, the result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBUbP.png) which is what I would expect.