# Can I add an image as the title of my legend?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, legend-properties

I have a figure with two subplots, each of them with their legend to the right. I would like to replace the title of each legend with a PNG image. My code, very downstripped:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

for ax in axes:
    # Add data and set up axes
    ...
    # Add legend
    lgd = ax.legend(loc='center right', ncol=1, borderaxespad=-10.0, fontsize=16, title='TITLE')
```

... where the value of the argument `title` would ideally be the image. Can this be done in a simple manner?

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029592/insert-image-in-matplotlib-legend), but it's a bit different in implementation (I am using `ax.legend` and not `plt.legend`), and also in concept (I need only the legend's title to be an image, and not all its elements). Also, I am hoping for a simpler solution.